# web project running in xampp server windows is not running in lamp server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I was using XAMPP server in windows to run my project and it works perfectly fine, but when I deployed the same project in LAMP server on ubuntu 16.04 the project is not running.It shows a blank screen.

Comment: Check the web server error logs to see if there might be any clues.

Comment: there are no errors in the web server error logs

Comment: the project is coded with php and mysql and it is very old..the project has files with extension of .phtml

Comment: Well, the simple thing to try on the Ubuntu machine, is to change the first few file extensions from `.phtml` to `.php` (such as the index.phtml, if you have one) and see if that helps. Otherwise, it'll be more involved to try and configure the setup for `.phtml` use.